# Open a browser window from an XUL application

Tags: url, browser, xul, xulrunner

How can I open a browser (i.e. Firefox, Chrome, IE, etc.) window from an XUL application?

I've tried the obvious `window.open(url, "_blank")` but the only effect this has is to close the current XUL window (!). A long trawl of Google hasn't produced anything fruitful either.

Just to make things clear, what I want is to open a URL in the user's default browser. I don't want to open the URL in my XUL application.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps you, but i use this to open a new tab.

```
var win = Components.classes['@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1']
    .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowMediator)
    .getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser');
win.gBrowser.selectedTab = win.gBrowser.addTab(myUrl);
```

You need to set `myURL` to the page you want to open.

More Information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Tabbed_browser)

Also note that this will surely not open IE or Chrome. I'm happy with that as long as it does not open IE:-)

Answer (score 1):

This is what I do:

```
function OpenInDefaultBrowser(uri)
{
    if(typeof uri == 'string')
    {
        var ioservice = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/io-service;1"]
            .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIIOService);
        uri = ioservice.newURI(uri, null, null);
    }

    // Open URL in user's default browser.
    var extps = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/uriloader/external-protocol-service;1"]
        .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIExternalProtocolService);
    extps.loadURI(uri, null);
}
```

Comment: +1 - This does the business but it nags for the user to select the appropriate application for the protocol (e.g. HTTP or HTPPS). Do you know of anyway around that?